# $uibModal TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, typeerror, servicenow

I am working in ServiceNow and have a button that pulls up a modal window that renders an embedded form.  When a user submits, I have the embedded form $broadcast 'closeModal', and the button receives it to close.  My client script looks like this for the embedded form:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('closeModal');
```

and on my button that brings up the modal, my client script looks like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('closeModal', function() {
        c.modalInstance.close();
    });
```

This actually does close the modal window, but my console is showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined"

[image]

Any idea why this is showing up?

Additionally, in my screenshot above, that typeerror actually shows up twice, for two different widgets.  I am broadcasting and retrieving the same event for both widgets.  I'm not sure if that's against best practice, but I've tried changing one of them to 'closeModal2' for example and the same typeError still shows.

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated!

**-- ADDED --**
This is a screenshot of my console after logging c:

[image]

Comment: Inside your handler mehtod c.modalInstance is undefined, try to inspect that element using Chrome developer tools or Firefox dev tools or print the content of c using console.log(c) post the results in your question to help solving it

Comment: thanks @guilhebl, posted above

Comment: One suggestion, try using `$rootScope.$emit('closeModal');` rather than `broadcast` if you are catching it on `$rootScope.$on`. Reason being, you are sending the event to all the `$scope` variables which you shouldn't do unless required. Its a good practive

Answer (score 0):

Simple hack is :

```
$rootScope.$on('closeModal', function() {
        c.modalInstance && c.modalInstance.close();
    });
```

Another suggestion is use `$rootScope.$emit` and listen at specific scope level `$scope.$on`